# Textarea within a php echoed html does not post value properly

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a file which includes 3 different pages which load on different situations which basically means all the html in the page is inside PHP tags and is echoed individually, they are loaded in this manner:

```
if ($page == 2) {
    global $wbdb;
    print_r($_SESSION['order']);
    print_r($_SESSION['order']);
    if($wpdb->last_error !== ''){
      $wpdb->print_error();
  }
```

I have a text area within the last page which I want to post the value inside the text area inside a variable I can use later on to post it to database like this:

```
  <textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] .
            $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'] . $comments; echo '</textarea>';
```

the issue here is that for no apparent reason this will always post null no matter what is attempted to add inside the textarea itself, everything else inside the page posts just fine but the textarea does not work at all. ask if something is unclear.

by request here is the full page code:

```
if ($page == 2) {
    global $wbdb;
    print_r($_SESSION['order']);
    print_r($_SESSION['order']);
    if($wpdb->last_error !== ''){
      $wpdb->print_error();
  }
    echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset ="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
      }

      .Etusivu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .margin {
        margin-bottom: 5%;
      }

      input[type=submit] {
        background-color: #cea525;
        color: white;
        padding: 1%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        float: right;
      }

      .important {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      .margin {
        margin-bottom: 5%;
      }

      input[type=submit] {
        background-color: #cea525;
        color: white;
        padding: 1%;
      }

      .important {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      textarea {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 95%;
        resize: none;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="Etusivu">
        <form action="" method="post" style="border:0px solid #ccc">
            <fieldset><legend><b>Tuotteiden palautus</b></legend>
              <div class="step">
            <legend>Askel 3/3</legend>
          </div>
          <br />
              <p class="important">Palautuksen varmistus</p>
              <br />
              <div class="valitse">
            <p class="important">Haluatko varmasti palauttaa seuraavat tuotteet?</p>
          </div>
            <hr>';
            $test = $_POST['productinfo'];
            $total2 = 0;
            for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
            list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode("|", $test[$i]);
            echo "Nimi: ".$name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Määrä: ".$quantity;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Hinta: ".$total . "€";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br/>";
            $total2 += $total;
}

            $_SESSION['product'] = $name;

            echo '
            <br />
            <br />
            <h4>Kirjoita alas, miksi haluat palauttaa tuotteen/tuotteet?</h4>
            <textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] .
            $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'] . $comments; echo '</textarea>';
            echo'

            <div class="refundprice">' .
            '<label>Palautettavien tuotteiden yhteishinta: ' . $total2 . '€' . '</label>
          </div>
            <div class="clearfix">
              <input type="hidden" name="page" value="3">
              <input type="submit" class="signupbtn" name="sendrqst" value="Lähetä">
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>';
    var_dump($comments);
  }

  echo "<a href='index.php'>Paina tästä päästäksesi takaisin etusivulle!</a>";
  if($wpdb->last_error !== ''){
    $wpdb->print_error();
}
```

Comment: can you post your code in detail? it is hard for me to analyze

Comment: You're code is really confusing `$comments = $_POST['comments'] . $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'] . $comments` this one has zero logic for me... What you're trying to achieve here ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki attempting to set the value inside the textarea into a variable and setting it into a session value after that

Comment: @David added the full code of the page in to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable outside of the textarea like :

```
$comments = $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'];

echo '<textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: Try this Veraen

Comment: Attempted with such, only returns NULL.

Comment: Then you may need to check first if `$_POST['comments']` isn't null

Comment: In Zakaria solution the $ is missing from comments variable, so if you copy pasted the code that might not be functional.

Also to make sure that your textarea is posting the content correctly just define the $comments variable above the textarea code with a random value, see if that gets posted, if yes than you have issues with the $_POST['comments'].

Comment: True @MicPic that may be the cause, good catch, retry Veraen with the `$` I have updated the answer

Comment: Where exactly do I need to check it? I am a little unsure as to where exactly to set it in there so it will check first before progressing.

Comment: `....placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments . '</textarea>';` the comment variable in this part

Comment: @MicPic for some strange reason even if I define it above for example as `$comments = "test";` the var dump on the same page returns NULL

Comment: You should define them before the `echo` that show the whole page

Comment: i edited a bit your code to make sure you understood what i meant:

$comments = 'test POST';
echo '      <br />
            <br />
            <h4>Kirjoita alas, miksi haluat palauttaa tuotteen/tuotteet?</h4>
   <textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments; 
echo '</textarea>';

try to replace with this and see if the $_POST['comments']  will be 'test POST'

Comment: @Veraen have you found the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
it seems to me you are only echoing '</textarea>', no? 
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments'];
echo '<textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments .'</textarea>';
```

Comment: Attempted making it like this 
`<textarea id="comments" name="comments" cols="30" rows="4" placeholder="Kirjoita tähän:">' . $comments = $_POST['comments'] .
            $_SESSION['commentone'] = $_POST['comments']; echo "$comments"; echo '</textarea>';`
with and without "" on $comments at the end